# Python: Unable to pass the url through web browser

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape the web data using python selenium, but when I am running the py code able to open the browser however it is not passing the url into web browser, below is the sample code I'm using.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

Chromepath = r"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"

url = "https://climate.weather.gc.ca/historical_data/search_historic_data_e.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chromepath)
driver.get(url)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Chrome driver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and then you may try something like this:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://climate.weather.gc.ca/historical_data/search_historic_data_e.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver') # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.
driver.get(url);
time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!
driver.quit()
```

[Read more here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started).

Comment: Thanks for your response Alpha.. Have a Good day.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issues fixed by installing the webdrivers.

```
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

# Chromepath = r"C:\\Program Files x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
Chromepath = r"C:\\Ecomm\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"
url = "https://climate.weather.gc.ca/historical_data/search_historic_data_e.html"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Chromepath)
driver.get(url)
```